# what is a best to way to push data to a remote hdfs using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I would like to push a local file to a remote hadoop machine. Is there a way to do that within python? Thanks.

Comment: just trying to know, why you want to push using python. Do you have a python script performing other actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hdfscli](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python module.

A simple example, for an HDFS environment whose Security is OFF, would look like

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient

hdfsclient = InsecureClient('http://nn_host:port', user='superuser')
hdfsclient.upload(hdfspath, localpath)
```

Use [`TokenClient`](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.TokenClient) or [`KerberosClient`](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.ext.kerberos.KerberosClient) based on Security Implementation.

**Note:** Requires `WebHDFS` (enabled by default)

Comment: That is the Web Interface port. `50070` by default.

Comment: Thanks. How to put in the password? Still not sure after reading documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Password of? Is `security` enabled? If not, It does not require any password. Else you have to take a look into the other two clients I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

hdfs_cmd = "hadoop fs -put local_file_path hdfs_file_path"

subprocess.call(hdfs_cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Why use Python at all? :P

Comment: He needs answer using python . We can put the file using python, java, ruby, shell script and scala

Comment: Your answer is only using Python to invoke a simple shell script, so I was just asking, why using Python at all here?

Comment: dear, i am not able to understand your question. we can use HDFS java API to do the above work. but all are will run in background as shell script

Comment: @KanagarajDhanapal what he means is that don't use python. Go for shell directly.